# Read host's ifconfig in the running Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, alpine-linux

I would like to read host's ifconfig output during the run of the Docker container, to be able to parse it and get OpenVPN interface (tap0) IP address and process it within my application.

Unfortunately, propagating this value via the environment is not my case, because IP address could change in time of running the container and I don't want to restart my application container each time to see a new value.

**Current working solution** is a CRON on the host which writes the IP into the file on a shared volume and container reads from it - but I am looking for better solution as it seems to me as a workaround. Also, there was a plan to create new container with `network: host` which will see host's interfaces - it works, but it also looks like a workaround as it involves many steps and probably security issues.

**I have a question, is there any valid and more clean way to achieve my goal - read host's ifconfig in docker container in realtime?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A specific design goal of Docker is that containers can’t directly access the host’s network configuration.  The workarounds you’ve identified are pretty much the only way to do these.

If you’re trying to modify the host’s network configuration in some way (you’re trying to actually run a VPN, for example) you’re probably better off running it outside of Docker.  You’ll still need root permission either way, but you won’t need to disable a bunch of standard restrictions to do what you need.

If you’re trying to provide some address where the service can be reached, using configuration like an environment variable is required.  Even if you could access the host’s configuration, this might not be the address you need: consider a cloud environment where you’re running on a cloud instance behind a load balancer, and external clients need the load balancer; that’s not something you can directly know given only the host’s network configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your response, which was the correct indicator, that I was doing something wrong by the design. After reading this, I've found the clean solution without need of propagating something from docker host. But eventually, if I'd need some value in realtime, it's probably the best to run this particular service as a container and communicate via HTTP - as it works in a standard setup.